# Movie Clip Not Showing in Background of Final Render or Output

Tags: rendering

I added the clip in while compositing to serve as a background to the logo animation. It shows up in the preview window of the composite node and viewer node, but not in the render of final output. Is it a setting I have not done correctly?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You using the alpha channel of the render layer to the output image, effectively making transparent the area where the background image should be.

Comment: Can I not make the logo transparent and still have a movie clip behind it? Am I missing a node?